# What can I give as an example for a dumb instrumentation system?

Tags: measurements, electronics, electrical-engineering

I've searched through many websites and textbooks but none of them have given an example for a dumb instrumentation device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:

the furnace thermostat in your house,
the cruise control in your car,
the battery charging system in an old-school car,
the water-filling system in your toilet- These are all "dumb" instrumentation devices in that they are non-adaptive i.e., incapable of altering or optimizing their system response.

If you want to get dumber:
a thermometer,
a speedometer,
a voltmeter,
a water valve- These are the dumbest because they take and report measurements but do not exert setpoint control to urge the system to a desired state- instead, a human has to do that in each case.